# Using `lineinfile` to add a host variable in Ansible YAML inventory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, inventory

Hello everybody and thank you in advance for your help.

I have to add a variable `stat: ON` for some hosts in my YAML inventory that looks like:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:     
    host_1: {db: true, bckp: false}
    host_2: {db: false, bckp: true}
```

To looks like:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:     
    host_1: {db: true, bckp: false, stat: ON}
    host_2: {db: false, bckp: true}
```

I want to add it with Ansible (`lineinfile` or other module) when I execute a task that power-on a VM.

I try this:

```yaml
- name: Add variable for with status stopped
  lineinfile:
    path: inventory/inv.yml
    insertafter: EOF
    line: "host_1: {db: true, bckp: false, stat: ON}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

But it's not OK because I have to give only the hostname not other values that I can't know in advance.

I try also:

```yaml
- name: Add variable for with status stopped
  add_host:
   name: host_1
   groups: group_name
   status: ON
 delegate_to: localhost
```

Not good because it add a new line instead of modify the existing one.

I've tried this also:

```yaml
- name: Read inventory file
  slurp:
    path: inventory/inv.yml
  register: inventory_content

- name: Parse YAML inventory
  set_fact:
    parsed_inventory: "{{ inventory_content.content | b64decode | from_yaml }}"

- name: Add variable for with status stopped
  set_fact:
    parsed_inventory: |
          {{ parsed_inventory | to_yaml | regex_replace('^(all:\s*hosts:\s*host_1:)', '\\1\n  status: ON') }}

- name: Write updated inventory file
  copy:
    content: "{{ parsed_inventory }}"
```

It's not good because it change all my inventory and not add the value.

All what I tried didn't work as I expect, I want to:

1. Find the line of given hostname (here `host_1`)
2. Insert the new variable after existing variables like:
   `host_1: {db: true, bckp: false}` -> `host_1: {db: true, bckp: false, stat: ON}`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables), for the given inventory file **`example.com`**

```ini
one.example.com db=true bckp=false
two.example.com db=true bckp=false
```

just introduce a **`host_vars/one.example.com`** file with content of

```yaml
stat: ON
```

in order to drop a fact and find an example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].stat
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --inventory example.com main.yml
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].stat: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].stat: true
```

There is absolute no need for parsing or editing a file, using `lineinfile`, `set_fact`, `regex_replace` or programming at all.

**Documentation**

- [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html)
- [Things to know about programming using Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-coding-programming)

  > *Ansible is not a language:
  > If Ansible isn't a programming language, then what is it? Ansible is a tool written in Python, and it uses the declarative markup language YAML to describe the Desired State of devices and configuration. ... You declare aspects you want to be configured on a target device, such as that a file or directory exists, a package is installed, a service is running, and so on.*
- [Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials)

  > *Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.*
- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576)

and finally

- [An introduction to Ansible facts](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/playing-ansible-facts)
- [Ansible Custom Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts)

Comment: Thank you for response, It's not what I want to do. I have not host_vars, I want to have the variable in my inventory as I explained

Comment: With the way I've showed it is in fact in your inventory.